# Finding a closed form for $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{k}{(k+1)!} $

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I'm finding a closed form to  $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{k}{(k+1)!}  (n \leq 1) $ (in a environment of induction and recurrence)

I've been trying to solve it without success, can anybody help me (?)

The last thing I've tried to do is write the expression as a Non-Homogeneous Linear Recurrence:

$ f(1) = \frac{1}{2} $

but, actually I have no idea of how to attach it. 
 $ f(n+1) = f(n) + \frac{1}{(n+2)n!} $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a telescopic series:
$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1)!}-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right)=\color{red}{1}$$
since:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(N+1)!}.$$

Comment: While the question actually asks about the _finite_ sum, the same idea can be applied there without problem.

Comment: This is useful but... How can I realize that                                                          
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(N+1)!}.$$ ?????

Comment: Ummm.... well, trying I've realize that for n=1: we have $ \frac{1}{2} $ which is the same that $1 - \frac{1}{2} $ and for n:2 we have $ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6} = 1 - \frac{1}{6}  $ and the same for n:3, we get it is $ 1 - \frac{1}{24} $ so... I have seen it. (But I'm afraid that I would not be able to realize that in a test but its 0k. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

prove by induction that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer is great, but if you are having difficult seeing the "since" portion of his answer, then consider the main portion of the inductive argument for establishing the identity that Jack gives:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!} &= \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}+\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}}\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&= \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}+\color{green}{\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right]}\tag{by ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}-\frac{(n+2)}{(n+2)!}\tag{manipulate}\\[1em]
&= 1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\tag{closed form}
\end{align}
Note that the portion highlighted in green is where you use the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplement to @JackDaurizio's *since* part which was asked by OP in a comment.

> It's all about *telescoping* in Jack's answer.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right)\\
> &=1-\frac{1}{(N+1)!}\\
> \end{align*}
>   It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k}{(k+1)!}\\
> &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(N+1)!}\right)\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}